# Understanding the definition of the d-dimensional Hyperube

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms, notation

Please see the picture bellow about the definition of the nodes of the d-dimensional Hypercube. Could anyone please tell me what does that notation means. I get confused with the superscript after the curly braces. What does that mean in set theory.

Nodes:  $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in\{0,1\}^d$

Edges:  $\forall i:(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\to(x_1,..,1-x_i,.. ,x_d)$

What does this mean? How are the nodes and the edges defined formally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\{0,1\}^d = \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \cdots \{0,1\}$ is just the Cartesian product $d$ copies of the set $\{0,1\}$. Thus the nodes $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_d) \in \{0,1\}^d \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ are just a vectors which we can think of as living in $\mathbb{R}^d$ where the components all have value 0 or 1. Then the edges of your graph just connect nodes that differ in exactly one component.

You can also think of $\{0,1\}^d$ as binary strings of length $d$, there is a clear bijection between the vectors described above and binary string of length $d$. Sometimes $\{0,1\}^d$ used to denote this set of strings, but the rest of your notation suggests the vector interpretation.

Try drawing the cases for $d=2$ and $d=3$ you should get a square and cube respectively.

Comment: so lets see if I understood it correctly: this notation "(x1,x2,…,xd)" represents a single node? @JMac31

Comment: Yes $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)$ is a single node.